# Margin on table

Tags: css, html-table

I have a margin-top problem on my `<table>`. The `<p>` is staggered for every line.
I have tried to define the table in CSS, but it doesn't work.

http://whatsyourproblem.dk/?page_id=89

Comment: What you have tried? What did not work? What you are trying to do?

Comment: The table in your link looks like it's doing what you'd expect...

Comment: margin-top is a space that above table border, not inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this to your td class and that will fix your issue.

```
  vertical-align: top;
```

*tested using firebug on the link you provided